# Storage image file to server

Tags: android, image-processing, webserver, storage

I'm developing a travel app. It has places which have images.

I have a database on my own server. My app reading image from that server database.

I'm confused between 2 choice for storage image:

1. Store the link of image on database. When app reading, download that image then display it
2. Store the encoded image on the database. When app reading, decode image and display.

which choice is better?

Comment: I do not understand. In option one, does the image sit somewhere on the Internet?

Comment: First one is better You should store the image link in database instead on encoded image because encoded image could take more database space when more images. When you need the images link in your app then use web service to get url of images.

Comment: @flup yes, it can be an url to that image.

Comment: Then in option one you save storage and bandwidth but risk it disappears. This may be good or bad.

Comment: @flup image on 1st storage on my server too. bandwidth usage may be equal. i want my app load as fast as possible

Answer (score 1):

It depends on different factors, such as image size and possibility to store in web-app folder of the server.
For ex: if your server has a public folder `http://server/public` and you have large images, you can store the image there  and the URL path on the DB. The app read the uri of the image and displays it. It's the faster solution. 
But if you haven't a public folder and you have little images, you can store as base64 image as a `Blob object` inside your database, and then get, decode and show the image on your app. It all depends on different factors.

Comment: If you allow your users to upload images to a public folder and serve them from there, you are effectively giving them free storage. So you do need to trust them with this.

Comment: @StarsSky i have a lot of image 300x180. So which choice is suitable for me??

Comment: Small images. I suggest you to store images on public path, but renaiming them with an guid or something else (random letters) so users can't find easily images on your public path ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID ). Set the complete path into the DB and retrieve/show images in your app. I think it's a easy solution.